# Algo como GetAsyncKeyState() para sistemas Linux, existe algo similar?

Tags: c++, shell

Eu pesquisei bastante na internet e não consegui encontrar algo como GetAsyncKeyState() que não esteja na biblioteca windows.h. Existe alguma biblioteca ou algum caminho a seguir que permita controle "direto" de coisas como saber se uma tecla está sendo pressionada ou, saber que tecla foi pressionada através de algum tipo de buffer?

Acho que seria algo como "controle das funções do teclado" ou "controle do estado dele". Eu gostaria de saber como isso funciona.

Provavelmente eu precise de usar alguma coisa de thread. Mas quanto a essa questão de ter controle sobre as coisas que são pressionadas, eu gostaria de um caminho quanto a isso, uma biblioteca para estudar... alguma coisa de shell script.. Alguma coisa que eu possa usar com o C++.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro da pasta `/dev/input` do seu Linux você vai ter informações sobre os eventos de *input* do seu sistema. Elas vêm no seguinte formato:

```
struct input_event {
    struct timeval time;
    unsigned short type;
    unsigned short code;
    unsigned int value;
};
```

> 'time' is the timestamp, it returns the time at which the event
>   happened. Type is for example EV_REL for relative moment, EV_KEY for a
>   keypress or release. More types are defined in
>   include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h.
>
> 'code' is event code, for example REL_X or KEY_BACKSPACE, again a
>   complete list is in include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h.
>
> 'value' is the value the event carries. Either a relative change for
>   EV_REL, absolute new value for EV_ABS (joysticks ...), or 0 for EV_KEY
>   for release, 1 for keypress and 2 for autorepeat.

Dentro desta [documentação](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt) você poderá ver como usar na parte de `2. Simple Usage`. Eu acredito que, no seu caso, um simples `fopen` do arquivo relativo ao seu input já vai ser necessário. Informações de `input` estão em `/usr/include/linux/input.h`.

Para pegar as informações use `read` para bloqueante ou `ioctl` para não bloqueante. Esse [tutorial](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6429?page=0,1) poderá te ajudar.

Olhe este exemplo:

```
FILE fd = fopen("/dev/input/eventX", "r"); //troque o path para o seu caso
char keys[16];
ioctl(fd, EVIOCGKEY(sizeof keys), &keys);
int keyb = keys[KEY_ESC/8]; //  ESC, por exemplo
int mask = 1 << (key % 8); 
bool state = !(keyb & mask);
```